# Android map coordinates of an image to an Imageview

Tags: android, draw

I want to draw at specific coordinates of an image which is displayed in an imageview. I use the src attribute of a imageview to load the image into the view. This code is used in an custom imageview to draw on the image:

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float scaleh =(float)canvas.getHeight()/(float)orginalheight();
    float scalew = ((float)canvas.getWidth()/(float)orginalwidth());
    canvas.drawRect(10*scaleh,9*scalew,20*scaleh,30*,scalewpaint);
}
```

This code draws the rectangle at the wrong location. What is wrong?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the dimensions of the View from the `ImageView` itself rather than `Canvas` especially when the ulterior goal is to Draw on Image inside `ImageView`.

> A Canvas works for you as a pretense, or interface, to the actual
>   surface upon which your graphics will be drawn — it holds all of your
>   "draw" calls. Via the Canvas, your drawing is actually performed upon
>   an underlying Bitmap, which is placed into the window.

Firstly, in order to get the Coordinates, implement `onTouchListener` for `ImageView`. This will give you X and Y co ordinates to draw the `Canvas` on.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

int action = event.getAction();
switch (action) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  xDown = event.getX();
  yDown = event.getY();
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
  xUp = event.getX();
  uUp = event.getY();
  canvas.drawLine(xDown, yDown, xUp, uUp, paint);
  imageView.invalidate();
  xDown = xUp;
  yDown = uUp;
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  xUp = event.getX();
  uUp = event.getY();
  canvas.drawLine(xDown, yDown, xUp, uUp, paint);
  imageView.invalidate();
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
  break;
default:
  break;
}

return true;
}});
```

Then create a `Canvas` to draw on top of ImageView.

```
//Create a new image bitmap and attach a brand new canvas to it
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(YOUR_DESIRED_COLOR);
paint.setStrokeWidth(INT_VALUE);
matrix = new Matrix();
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

//Attach the canvas to the ImageView
imageViewsetImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
```

you can also use `canvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,paint);` if you want to draw Rectangle simply.

Hope it helps.